# Rx Swift simple timer not working

Tags: timer, swift3, observable, rx-swift

I have this RxSwift code in swift 3

```
let bag:DisposeBag = DisposeBag()
var sig:Observable<Int>!
sig = Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)

sig.subscribe(onNext: { (milsec) in
    print("Mil: \(milsec)")
}).addDisposableTo(bag)
```

i run this code when button tapped, but its not print anything on console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DisposeBag` will dispose of your subscription once it goes out of scope. In this instance, it'll be right after the call to subscribe, and it explains why you don't see anything printed to the console.

Move the definition of dispose bag to the class creating the subscription and everything should work fine.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  let bag:DisposeBag = DisposeBag()

  dynamic func onButtonTapped() {
    var sig:Observable<Int>!
    sig = Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)

    sig.subscribe(onNext: { (sec) in
        print("Sec: \(sec)")
    }).addDisposableTo(bag)
  }
}
```

---

On a side note, `interval` expects an interval in seconds, so it will only tick every seconds as oposed to milliseconds.